# Is there a way to keep a private repo on Github synced with another public repo?

Tags: git, github, heroku, hosting, heroku-cli

I have a project that is hosted on Heroku from a private repo on my github.
I also have a public version on github, from which I've removed the environment variables and other sensitive data. Now I want people to contribute to the project. Is there a way that I can sync changes in the public repo with the private repo as well so that my hosted website stays updated?